# If the __gt__() condition is inverted for two class instances in a heapq, does the heap notice?

Tags: python, class

I have a bunch of nodes in a heapq and their `__gt__()` compared on their heuristic. Sometimes their heuristics update when an `__eq__()` happens.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.state == other.state:
        self.heur = min(self.heur, other.heur)
        return True
.
.

def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.heur > other.heur
```

Here, will the heapq notice that the values `__gt__` compares have changed and restructure instantly or do I have to heapify each time?

Comment: Less words, more code. Please.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes (of course). As a side note, I would tell you that changing the state of the object inside the comparison operator `__eq__` is conceptually wrong, and that you should try to find a different solution.